# SQL Server: issue with UNION ALL and two Selects

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, union, union-all

I am pretty new to SQL and might be doing something wrong here so I hope someone can help me with this.

I have a longer stored procedure that ends with the below. 
The idea here is to combine two queries into one so that I don't need a separate stored procedure but still have the results separated as one selects by a country (`selCountry`) and the other selects by a date (`selDate`).

When I try to save it this way I get the error: "`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'`.
When I run them in separate procedures then everything works fine.

```
-- create final output
SELECT      CONVERT(DATETIME, dDay) AS dDay,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), dDay, 106) AS dLong,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dDay, 126) AS dShort,
            countries,
            regions,
            mode,
            dName,
            dDesc
FROM        @tempFix
WHERE       countries LIKE '%'+@selCountry+'%'
OR          regions LIKE '%'+@selCountry+'%'
ORDER BY    dDay
UNION ALL
SELECT      CONVERT(DATETIME, dDay) AS dDay,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), dDay, 106) AS dLong,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dDay, 126) AS dShort,
            countries,
            regions,
            mode,
            dName,
            dDesc
FROM        @tempFix
WHERE       DAY(dDay) = DAY(@selDate)
AND         MONTH(dDay) = MONTH(@selDate)
FOR XML PATH('dDays'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('root')
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this, Mike.

Comment: The order by goes at the very end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove the ORDER BY and add it to the very end. You cannot place ORDER BY before UNION / UNION ALL.

**[Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/10/30/sql-server-union-all-and-order-by-how-to-order-table-separately-while-using-union-all/)**'s more information about this syntax.

Comment: Thanks for this - that worked ! - Thanks for all the other posts as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can't include `ORDER BY` until after the last query in the `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the ORDER BY clause only at the end of all set operations in your query